# Problems setting unsigned int for bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, size, int

this is the file structure for my bitmap info header

```
// the info header to store reveleant bitmap data
struct InfoHeader
{
    unsigned int biSize;        // the bit size
    unsigned int width;     
    unsigned int height; 
    unsigned short biPlanes;    // number planes
    unsigned short biBitCount;  // number of bits for each pixel
    unsigned int biCompression; // compression used
    unsigned int size;  // size of image
    unsigned int biXPelsPerMeter;       // unit of measurement for x
    unsigned int biYPelsPerMeter;       // unit of measurement for y
    unsigned int biClrUsed; // number of colours
    unsigned int biClrImportant;
};
```

I believe that it conforms to the structure represented on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

but when I try setting the size of the image via

```
bitmapInfoHeader.size = (width*height*3);
```

Where width and height are both unsigned ints, size ALWAYS gets set to 0. 
I've been playing around for ages with this, any help please?

EDIT: Both width and height are passed in via arguments to the method (writeBitmapFile) and are both initialised (I have tested this)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use C or C++ as a programming language?

Comment: Please retag your question... Which programming language etc... Like this the awnser is: `width` or `height` is 0.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `bitmapInfoHeader.size = (bitmapInfoHeader.width*bitmapInfoHeader.height*3);`? And did you ever initialize `width` and `height`? If so, can you construct an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) reproducing the problem?

Comment: sorry guys, it is C++ and both width and height are passed in via arguments to the method (and yes both width and height have values) 

The brakets are there just to clarify the calculations to be made before assigning it to the .size value.

And @Dukeling the width and height values are assigned to the infoheader.width and infoheader.height values before hand anyway, they are exactly the same so it shouldn't matter :)

Comment: I fixed it! Turns out the bit allignment was off in the FileHeader and needed to inclose BitmapFileHeader with

    #pragma pack(2)

and close it with

    #pragma pack()

this made sure the short values in the structure were properly alligned when reading in the binary data

Answer (score 0):

Closed by the OP on May 29. He was populating the struct by doing a big slurp up from a .BMP file (using `fread` or the equivalent), and the layout of his struct fields in memory didn't match the layout of the fields in the file. Nothing exciting here.